# Where are default account owner sharing access levels defined?

Tags: salesforce

By default Salesforce accounts in my org have the following sharing rule in place for account owners:

- Type: User
- Name: < Owner_Name >
- Account Access: Full Access
- Contact Access: Read/Write
- Opportunity Access : Read/Write
- Case Access: Read only
- Reason: Owner

Does anyone know where the default access levels for contacts, opportunities, and cases is defined?  I've researched sharing in the help docs and api references as well as the salesforce dev boards and stack overflow and haven't been able to find anything about what controls the default values for the access levels.

Comment: Hi, I posted the same question in SFSE. Could you please answer there?http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/133201/default-sharing-access-levels-for-account-owner

Answer (score 1):

Setup -> Administraction Setup -> Security Controls -> Sharing Settings.

The Organization-Wide Defaults are all at the top.